# How to parse full text webpage from this page?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, html-parsing

I need to get the track names from this page but i get uncomplete response

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://parmismedia1.com/musicplayeralbum.aspx?album=666&amp;id=8503&amp;title=farzad-farzin-6-to-che-bashi"));
```

I used firefox inspector, sent post request, used mobile and desktop user agent strings but stil got uncomplete response.
but i noticed that i get the full page text when i create a download task on uc browser with that address.
How can i get the complete page text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still figuring out why the client.GetStringAsync is not working, but I was able to get the page html by using System.Net.HttpWebRequest.

Code sample below.

```cs
Uri address = new Uri("http://parmismedia1.com/musicplayeralbum.aspx?album=666&id=8503&title=farzad-farzin-6-to-che-bashi");
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
httpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
httpRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
httpRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0";
httpRequest.Method = "GET";
httpRequest.Timeout = 3000;
HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

response.Close();
```

Comment: it works and i get page text but i mean it doesnt include the part that contains tracks list. if you open the page on browser you can see the part on left containing album cover and tracks and that part is not included on parsed text.

Comment: does ur response text include track names?

Comment: Yes, it does. Maybe you're using the VS string inspector and sometime it doesn't show all the content of a big string. Try addind somethign like System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\test.txt", html); and see the result in the file. Or test in your code for a song name like bool containsThirdSong = html.Contains("3 - Dir Omadi");.

Comment: yeah you are right. text visualizer doesn't show full text. i can see full text by JSON visualizer.  i always used text visualizer with no problem. can't believe i was stuck for this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In a test app, I used a valid URL (by not using `&amp;` in the request instead using an ampersand `&` directly), and the response returns correctly:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://parmismedia1.com/musicplayeralbum.aspx?album=666&id=8503&title=farzad-farzin-6-to-che-bashi"));
```

That being said, your original query also returns successfully, it's just doing several redirects before it fully returns.

[image: Redirects]

But, I did notice that the HTML page being returned isn't entirely valid as it contains error information at the beginning of the response:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\PMWebsite\Log\500_2016-04-03.log' because it is being used by another process.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="app">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /><title>
```

You might want to check with the creators of the web site to check whether scraping their web application content is OK and if they might have a direct API you could use instead.